# Printing and parsing JSON variable in PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

I've the following PHP code with a JSON variable...

```
$route_geometry_json = "{
    \"route_geometry\": [
        [44.911537, 7.671326],
        [44.911481, 7.671462],
        [44.911455, 7.671531],
        [44.911434, 7.671602],
        [44.911358, 7.671859],
        [44.911273, 7.672175],
        [44.911198, 7.672458],
        [44.91113, 7.672617],
        [44.911069, 7.67275],
        [44.911003, 7.672821],
        [44.910945, 7.672881],
        [44.910869, 7.672954],
        [44.910868, 7.673046],
        [44.91091, 7.673109],
        [44.91095, 7.67319],
        [44.910964, 7.673266],
        [44.910958, 7.673407],
        [44.910955, 7.6735],
        [44.910947, 7.673632],
        [44.910922, 7.673871],
        [44.910828, 7.674786],
        [44.910711, 7.675816],
        [44.910606, 7.676364],
        [44.910467, 7.676322],
        [44.910368, 7.676308],
        [44.910051, 7.676253],
        [44.9097, 7.676162],
        [44.90944, 7.676041],
        [44.909297, 7.675958],
        [44.909174, 7.67583],
        [44.909107, 7.675722],
        [44.908993, 7.675583],
        [44.908758, 7.675448],
        [44.90796, 7.675037]
    ]
  }";

print "Route geometry -->" + json_encode($route_geometry_json);
```

The print return "**0**": any suggestion / example?

I'd like also to extract / print the coords couples like

```
    44.908993, 7.675583
    44.908758, 7.675448
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated ...

Thanks

Cesare

Comment: yep, encode converts a value to json, while decode converts a json to a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$route_geometry = json_decode($route_geometry_json);

foreach ($route_geometry->route_geometry as $value) {
    echo $value[0].', '.$value[1].'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `print_r(json_decode($route_geometry_json))` it and **not** `json_encode`

`json_encode` is for creating a JSON string. But since you already have a JSON string already, you need to Decode it to make it an Array/Object.

**UPDATE**

Your requirement

```
echo "Route geometry -->"; 
print_r(json_decode($route_geometry_json));
```

You cannot concat a `String` and an `Object`, so you were getting that Parse error.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried but the result is ..... "Notice: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int ....." :-(

Comment: use `print_r` to print

Comment: I've tried to use "print_r" to print and now the error is "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"Route geometry -->"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)" ....

Comment: remove the back slashes from the string and it should work ... "route_geometry" and use single quotes for the whole string. Try

Comment: Do not use `print "Route geometry -->" + `.. This is the actual issue I think @Cesare

Comment: I've checked my JSON now it's ok ..... but I obtain again "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"Route geometry -->"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)". The command is .... print_r "Route geometry -->" + json_decode($route_geometry_json);

Comment: do this `echo "Route geometry -->"; print_r(json_decode($route_geometry_json));`

Comment: Because you cannot concat, a string and a Object as one. So, print them differently.

Comment: @Cesare Do accept the answer if it worked for you. Thanks!